# Javascript - Replace text if tag contains specific text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Wordpress and I need to replace a text if a tag contains a specific text. I'm not very familiar with Javascript so I hope someone here can help me :)

This is my html structure:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="tr1">
<td class="td1">
<a href="http://www.example.com">Name 1</a>
<strong class="quantity">× 1</strong>
</td>
<td class="td2">
<span class="span1">30$</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

- If span class="span1" = "30$" or if span class="span1" ="40$"
- Then "Name 1" needs to be replaced by "Name 2"
- If not (= span is something else than 30 or 40), then the script must not run.
- The "Name 2" will be the same with a span = 30 or 40.

I hope my explanation is clear enough. I tried to search first by myself, I found some functions such as getelement and innerHTML but I didn't find how to combine it with the result I need.

Thank you!

EDIT: I would like to target the tag A with the specific href="http://www.example.com"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)**,**[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** and **[`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)** and do something like this

```js
function changeTxt() {
  // get all spans
  var ele = document.querySelectorAll('.td2 .span1');
  // iterate over the html element collection
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    // parse the text to get number
    // if symbol is in starting following will not work
    // var text = parseFloat(ele[i].innerHTML, 10);
    var text = parseFloat(ele[i].innerHTML.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/)[0], 10);
    // check the value is 30 or 40
    if (text == 30 || text == 40) {
      // if true then  get current tr and get anchor tag and update content
      var item = ele[i]
        // getting closest ancestor tr
        .closest('tr')
        // select a tag which have particular attribute value
        .querySelector('.tad1 a[href="http://www.example.com"]')
        // check item exists and update
      if (item) {
        item.innerHTML = 'Name 2';
        // disabling click event (since disabled attribute will not work)
        //item.setAttribute('onClick', "return false;");
        //or remove the href attribute
        item.removeAttribute('href');
        // or
        // item.setAttribute('href','#');
      }
    }
  }
}
changeTxt();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr1">
      <td class="tad1">
        <a href="http://www.example.com">Name 1</a>
        <strong class="quantity">× 1</strong>
      </td>
      <td class="td2">
        <span class="span1">30.0$</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr1">
      <td class="tad1">
        <a href="http://www.example.com">Name 1</a>
        <strong class="quantity">× 1</strong>
      </td>
      <td class="td2">
        <span class="span1">30.1$</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr1">
      <td class="tad1">
        <a href="http://www.example.com">Name 1</a>
        <strong class="quantity">× 1</strong>
      </td>
      <td class="td2">
        <span class="span1">20$</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr1">
      <td class="tad1">
        <a href="http://www.example.com">Name 1</a>
        <strong class="quantity">× 1</strong>
      </td>
      <td class="td2">
        <span class="span1">£30</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr1">
      <td class="tad1">
        <a href="#">Name 1</a>
        <strong class="quantity">× 1</strong>
      </td>
      <td class="td2">
        <span class="span1">30$</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Problem. Query selector returns 1 element. What if the table have two or more rows? You need to write with `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: You need to use `querySelectorAll` and iterate over them

Comment: That's what I've said.

Comment: Thank you Pranav. Can I specify in the querySelector('.tad1 a') that I want to select only the .tad1 a with href="http://www.example.com" please?

Comment: attributes can be specified in CSS selectors using the square bracket syntax: `[attr=value]`. So you'd want to make it something like: `....querySelector('.tad1 a[href=example.com]')`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Alright thank you. Last thing, I will have something like 5 to 10 different href where the value needs to change. If there a quick way to integrate it into the code please?

Comment: @Ludo65 add them `,` separated like `'.tad1 a[href="http://www.example.com"],'.tad1 a[href="http://www.other.com"]`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Okay i see! i forgot to mention something: I also need to deactivate the link on the specific a. So whenever "Name 1" is replaced by "Name 2" then "Name 2" link must be deactivate.

Comment: @PranavCBalan If I run the code snippet, I still have a link on Name 2

Comment: @Ludo65 click action will not work even if the link is there.... or instead remove `href` attribute or set `#` as value

Comment: @PranavCBalan Also, I'm sorry but actually the amount is in pound, I thought I would be able to switch it easily but it doesnt seem to work.. :/ Can you update the script to work with "£30" instead of "30$" ? Sorry for that..

Comment: @PranavCBalan Oh okay for the click action, that's perfect thanks :) I hope you can update with the £ and that should be it!

Comment: @PranavCBalan I tried to add an amount with a decimal but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to have both 30 and 30.5 working within the same script? If it's possible I could be great to have this flexibility, thank you

Comment: @Ludo65 : updated regex and used parseFloat instead of parseInt

Comment: @PranavCBalan thank you however it is only working with ".0", with 30.1 or even 30.56 (as some amounts may have 2 decimals) it is not working. Do you know why?

Comment: @PranavCBalan Oh I thought if you put "30" in the value to check and if the amount if "30.5" it will take it because if the amount is "30.0" then it's working, so I thought the rule was: if amount = 30.xx, no matter what is the "x". My mistake, sorry I'm really not good with js (I'm in business school not dev). Anyway sounds like it's okay perfect now. I just need to find out how to implement it on wordpress now, but I should find a plugin for that :) So thank you very much for your help Pranav, you're awesome!

Comment: @Ludo65 : for that you just need to use parseInt instead of parseFloat

Comment: @Ludo65 :  glad to help you buddy :)

Comment: @Ludo : or use regex as `/\d+/` or `Math.floor()`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thank you so much for your help. And thanks for the "item.setAttribute" function, I used it to set a new href url :)